# Strange HTTP_ Prefix in $_SERVER key

Tags: php, jquery, nginx, server

I am sending an jQuery AJAX to a server file.
These are the headers I do set:

```
headers: {
  'X-FOO': 'x_foo',
  'X-BAR': $( 'input[name=x_bar]' ).val(),
}
```

On the server side, `$_SERVER` has all those headers, *but* the `'X-BAR'` header (and *only* this one) is prefixed with an `HTTP_` (doubled up).

So on the server side, if I look at `$_SERVER`, I get (amongst all other things), this:

```
...
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en;q=0.9
[HTTP_X_FOO] => x_foo
[HTTP_HTTP_X_BAR] => my_value
[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
...
```

Notice how the `HTTP_` is present twice?!

If it is of importance, it is an NGINX install (without CMS or else interfering, just plain PHP/jQuery)

Could anyone think of a reason why this happens?
(*No, I am 100% sure I do not pass that additional prefix in the AJAX header*. I checked :) )

Comment: Are those the real, actual header names you are sending? Wondering if this could perhaps be due to a "collision" with some already existing one perhaps.

Comment: If "$( 'input[name=x_bar]' ).val()  " is NULL header will be sent without key 'X-BAR. Before send try show alert(  $( 'input[name=x_bar]' ).val()   ) to check what value is set;

Comment: For mysterious reasons, it is _not happening anymore_. Confused, but moving on,I guess it is one of those oddities of the "precise" world of bits and numbers I will never understand :)